# extending basket js functionality to load a script dynamically

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to extend [basketjs](http://addyosmani.github.io/basket.js/) functionality. i want to load the script dynamically via [basketjs](http://addyosmani.github.io/basket.js/). But i have a problem with that.

first, i scan all the DOM to get my own data-attribute. then convert the array into object and pass them to basketjs. well, it works without their promise function. My plan is i loop them all, the 1st script is passed without promise, the rest are using promise.

objects :

```
var obj: [
 {
   url: 'first_script.js',
   skipCache: true
 },
 {
   url: 'second_script.js',
   skipCache: true
 },
 {
   ...
 }
];
```

function :

```
var forEach = function (array, callback, scope) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    callback.call(scope, i, array[i]);
  }
};

var i = 0;
forEach(obj, function (i) {
  if (i === 0) {
    console.log('load first_script');
    basket.require(obj[0]);
  } else {
    console.log('load the second_script and others');
    basket.require( obj[i] );
  }
});
```

Goal : I want to load the second_script and others using `.then(function({ basket.require( ... )` so i can ordering the scripts.

Anybody can help me? any help will be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: What exactly is it you're trying to accomplish? Do I understand you correctly, that your goal is to know when the first script has finished loading and then only get a notification when all the other scripts have been loaded?

Comment: i edit the question and test it.

my goal is i want to use basket function within my loop. 
i want to get the same effect when i'm using : 
basket.require({ url: first_script.js}).then(function(){ basket.require({ url: second_script.js } )});

but i want to loop another then function as long as my loop.

sorry for bad explanation. hope it explains.  :(

Comment: So you want to include one script after another. So you need to wait till script1.js has been loaded to include script2.js?

Comment: yess it is! :) do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write a little recursive function to do that. The algorithmn is very simple.

```
function loadScripts(scripts, onFinish) {
    if(scripts.length === 0) {
        onFinish();
        return;
    }

    var script = scripts[0];
    scripts = scripts.slice(1);

    basket.require(script).then(function() { loadScripts(scripts, onFinish); });
}
```

The function takes two arguments:

1. The array of dependency items
2. The callback when all dependencies have been included.

It is a recursive function so it has to start with a check if it has finished. If there are no scripts to include we're ready. Otherwise we take and remove the first element from the array and require the script. When it has been loaded we call the function on the rest of the array and the same callback.

That's it. Here's a working example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arw3b10k/1/)

Comment: this is trully awesome!
thanks for pointing it out and your great explanation. :)